# Check list items for div and add class if no content

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with 2 items - one has an image, one does not

```
<ul class="listings news">
    <li>
        <div class="image">
            <a href="/"><img src="images/temp/inner1.jpg" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <h3><a href="/">Sub-section title link</a></h3>
            <p>Text content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="content">
            <h3><a href="/">Sub-section title link</a></h3>
            <p>Text content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to find the one which has no image and add a class to either the LI or the 'content' Div - so far this finds it but adds the class to all LI divs instead of jsut the one without the image:

```
if ($(".news li").find(".image").length > 0){
    $(".content").addClass("no-thumb");
}
```

have tried lots of variations, using the 'has' function etc but no joy - any help appreciated

Cheers
.ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $(".news li").each(function () {
        $(this).find('.image').parent().addClass("no-thumb");
    });
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0p3oqzfe/)

Problem was that `$(".news li")` returns all `li` from your news container (so `$(".news li").find(".image").length > 0` is always `false` if you have at least one) but you want to iterate through every individual item.

Also you should be aware that `$(".content").addClass("no-thumb");` sets class to **every** element with `content` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on all `li` childs of element which has class **news** and check if it does not have child element with class **image** add **no-thumb** class to its child element which has class **content**

You can do it like this:

```js
$(".news li").each(function () {
    
    if ($(this).find(".image").length == 0) {  // check if div with class image not exists
        $(this).find(".content").addClass("no-thumb"); // add class to content div
    }

});
```

```css
.no-thumb {
    background-color:red;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="listings news">
    <li>
        <div class="image"> <a href="/"><img src="images/temp/inner1.jpg" alt=""></a>

        </div>
        <div class="content">
             <h3><a href="/">Sub-section title link</a></h3>

            <p>Text content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="content">
             <h3><a href="/">Sub-section title link</a></h3>

            <p>Text content</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution that avoids an explicit loop is using jQuery's :has selector.

```
$(".news li:not(:has(.image))").find('.content').addClass("no-thumb");
```

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7cm74x8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".news li").each(function(){
    if($(this).find(".image").length < 1){
       $(".content",this).addClass("no-thumb");
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8076bdj/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get all the `li` elements which do not contain a `.image` element and add the `no-thumb` class to the `li` element.

`$("li").not($("li").has(".image")).addClass("no-thumb")`

**EDIT:** Here is a fiddle demonstrating this code in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwnace/ryqyr2p3/